# WC isn't executing anything

Tags: c, fork

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? I'm still a newbie with forking. The computer executes the 1st and 2nd but the 3rd which is wc doesn't work. Need help badly. The terminal returns multiple child process completed but no wc.

```
pid_t son;
int i;

for (i=0; i<=3; i++){
        switch (i){
            case 0:
            son = fork();
                if (son<0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed!");
                    //exit(-1);
                }else if (son == 0){
                    execlp("/bin/cat", "cat", "wctrial.txt", NULL);
                    exit(0);
                }else{
                wait(NULL);
                printf("Child process completed!");

                }
            case 1:
            son = fork();
                if (son<0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed!");
                    //exit(-1);
                }else if (son == 0){
                    execlp("/bin/mkdir", "mkdir", "mydirectory", NULL);
                    exit(0);
                }else{
                wait(NULL);
                printf("Child process completed!");
                }
            case 2:
            son = fork();
                if (son<0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed!");
                    //exit(-1);
                }else if (son == 0){
                    printf("Work!");
                    execlp("usr/bin/wc","wc","-w","wctrial.txt", NULL);
                    exit(0);
                }else{
                wait(NULL);
                printf("Work!");
                printf("Child process completed!");
                exit(0);
                }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot the leading slash in the path.

Comment: You forgot newlines `\n` at end of `printf` format strings, and calling `fflush` (at least just before `fork`). Also, compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g` and debug it with `gdb`  or at least `strace`

Comment: what u mean leading slash?

Comment: `"usr/bin/wc"` should be `"/usr/bin/wc"`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch how do you do fflush?

Comment: Call `fflush(NULL)` and please read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch another questio, how can I wc from a directory like usr/bin/sbin?

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

You forgot the leading slash in the path. –  Joachim Pileborg

"usr/bin/wc" should be "/usr/bin/wc" –  Basile Starynkevitch